# Как расположить только 3 блока на строке, с переносом остальных

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не могу сделать так чтобы остальные блоки(начиная с текста 4) перенеслись на другую строку. Вот код:

```css
.catalog {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.catalog ul {
  width: 30%
}

.serialy {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.cartocki {
  width: 30%;
  height: 25vh;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.cartocki img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">&#8249</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">&#8250</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="serialy" id="serialy"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задайте li - 33.333% либо используйте Grid

Comment: С процентами не работает, сейчас уже 60 стоит и они просто прекратили увеличение с 30. Кроме Grid-а никак? я его пока не изучал.

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap` - есть?

Comment: нет, не добавлял.

Comment: попробуйте, иначе переноса не будет